# blogengine and mysql .net connector - fail to connect to db

Tags: mysql, blogengine.net

ive got a problem when trying to connect to a mysql db for blogengine (1.5.0) using mysql .net connector.

im getting "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts" error.

`[SocketException (0x273d): The attempted operation is not supported for the type of object referenced]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.get_ConnectEx() +305
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnectEx(EndPoint remoteEP, Boolean flowContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +479
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.BeginConnect(EndPoint remoteEP, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +125
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.CreateSocketStream(IPAddress ip, Boolean unix) +187
   MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout) +495
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +234`

[MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.]
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() +299
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) +48
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection() +11
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection() +190
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() +129
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection() +106
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open() +293
   BlogEngine.Core.Providers.DbBlogProvider.LoadSettings() +201
   BlogEngine.Core.BlogSettings.Load() +63
   BlogEngine.Core.BlogSettings..ctor() +25
   BlogEngine.Core.BlogSettings.get_Instance() +29
   BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.ReferrerModule..cctor() +71

[TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.ReferrerModule' threw an exception.]

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandle& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean fillCache) +86
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks, Boolean fillCache) +230
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +67
   System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +1051
   System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +111
   System.Web.Configuration.Common.ModulesEntry.Create() +39
   System.Web.Configuration.HttpModulesSection.CreateModules() +164
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitModules() +28
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitInternal(HttpContext context, HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers) +729
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetNormalApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +298
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetApplicationInstance(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +289

what ive done so far:

1)tried to connect to my shared hosting mysql account

2)tried connect to my localhost server

3)tried changing .net connector from versoin 5.1.7 until 6.0.5

4)tried restarting IIS

and im still getting the error. i could connect to both server (shared n local) using mysql administrator n query browser. so theres no way its a firewall issue plus i already enable port 3306.

anyone experienced something like this before ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i guess i found the problem. its got to do with my winsock. it was corrupted.

so all i did was netsh winsock reset . restart the pc, and i can connect to the db.